# Tablesorter not correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I am using Stupid TableSorter Javascript, but having some problems, because i am using Danish money format.

Ex. table:

```
 0,00         18,75
 0,00         112,50
 4.744,68     562,50
 1.125,00     15%
```

The highest is 4.744,68. in first column, and the highest in second column is "562,50". But when i am trying to tablesort, it doesn't do it right.

I have tried < th .... data-sort="float" > and also data-sort="int" and also "string". But it doesn't do it correct, maybe because of my danish number format, but how to fix it?

I am using: http://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data-sort-value`

> If you have data in both a machine friendly form and human friendly
>   form, you can provide the machine friendly value to data-sort-value on
>   table cells. The plugin will sort by the value provided but display
>   the human friendly form to the user.

ex:

```
<td data-sort-value="4744.68">4.744,68</td>
```